# How do I communicate from visualforce page to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to use paypal's buttons to add to my lwc. I made a visualforce page to run the scripts that it needs and I added it to the lwc using an iframe. I just want a string value to get passed from the visualforce page to the apex class. I also want the visual page to update with a new value after I pass in the ID from the LWC. I have it as a hardcoded value right now.

```
paypal.page
<apex:page controller="paypalValues" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="true" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" applyBodyTag="False" applyHtmlTag="False" >

<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!setParams}" name="setParams" rerender="dummy">
        <apex:param name="capturedData" assignTo="{!capturedData}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>

<body>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<!-- Sample PayPal credentials (client-id) are included -->
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD&intent=capture&enable-funding=venmo" data-sdk-integration-source="integrationbuilder"></script>
<script>
    console.log("In vfp")
  
    const paypalButtonsComponent = paypal.Buttons({
      // optional styling for buttons
      // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/buttons-style-guide/
      style: {
        color: "gold",
        shape: "rect",
        layout: "vertical"
      },

      // set up the transaction
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          // pass in any options from the v2 orders create call:
          // https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body
          const createOrderPayload = {
              purchase_units: [
                  {
                      amount: {
                          value: {!fullval}
                      }
                  }
              ]
          };

          return actions.order.create(createOrderPayload);
      },

      // finalize the transaction
      onApprove: (data, actions) => {

          const captureOrderHandler = (details) => {
              const payerName = details.payer.name.given_name;
              const status = details.status;   
          };
        //   ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message("Success"));

            capturedData = "Success"
            return actions.order.capture().then(captureOrderHandler);
      },

      // handle unrecoverable errors
      onError: (err) => {
          console.error('An error prevented the buyer from checking out with PayPal');
      }
  });

  paypalButtonsComponent
      .render("#paypal-button-container")
      .catch((err) => {
          console.error('PayPal Buttons failed to render');
      });




</script>
</body>

{!capturedData}
<!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

```
paypalValues.cls
public with sharing class paypalValues {

    public static string fullval { get; set;}
    public static string capturedData { get; set;}

    public paypalValues(){
        String id = '005Do000000JHJhIAO';
        Tenant__c myid = [Select Lease__c from Tenant__c where user__c = :id ];
        Lease__c lea = [Select Total__c from Lease__c where id = :myid.Lease__c];
        String s = String.valueOf(lea.Total__c);
        fullval = s;
    }

    public PageReference setParams()
    {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));
        return null;
    }

    public string setData(string val){
        capturedData = val;
        return capturedData;
    }

    public string sendCapturedData()
    {

        return apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Success');
    }

    public static string sendCapturedData(string val)
    {
        return apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Success');
    }

}
```

```
payrent.js
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getRentFromUser from '@salesforce/apex/getRecords.getRentFromUser'
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'
// import updateValues from '@salesforce/apex/paypalValues.updateValues'


export default class PayRent extends LightningElement {

buttons
rent
month
date
isEnabled = false
hasPetFees = false
hasParkingFees = false
hasAdditionalFees = false

@track capturedData = 'ello'

@wire(getRentFromUser, {id : Id})
gtRent(res){
    if(res.data)
    {
        this.rent = res.data
        this.isEnabled = true

        if(res.data.Pet_Fees__c)
            this.hasPetFees = true

        if(res.data.Parking_Fees__c)
            this.hasParkingFees = true

        if(res.data.Additional_Fees__c)
            this.hasAdditionalFees = true

        const [year, month, day] = res.data.Last_Payed__c.split('-');
        this.date = new Date(+year, month - 1, +day).toLocaleDateString();
      
        if(month == 1)
            this.month = "January"
        else if(month == 2)
            this.month = "February"
        else if(month == 3)
            this.month = "March"
        else if(month == 4)
            this.month = "April"
        else if(month == 5)
            this.month = "May"
        else if(month == 6)
            this.month = "June"
        else if(month == 7)
            this.month = "July"
        else if(month == 8)
            this.month = "August"
        else if(month == 9)
            this.month = "September"
        else if(month == 10)
            this.month = "October"
        else if(month == 11)
            this.month = "November"
        else if(month == 12)
        this.month = "December"

        this.month = this.month.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

```
payrent.html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div  class="slds-p-around_x-small">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
            <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
            <font size="3">
                <div class="slds-border_bottom slds-p-around_x-small">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters ">
                        <template if:true={isEnabled}>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <Strong>CURRENT BALANCE: ${rent.Rent_Payed_So_Far__c}</Strong><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <Strong>AS OF: {date}</Strong><br/>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </font>
            <div class="slds-border_bottom slds-p-around_x-small">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font size="5">
                    <strong>{month} MONTHLY CHARGES</strong>
                </font>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-border_bottom slds-p-around_x-small">
                <div  class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-around_x-small">
                        <div  class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                            <font size="2">
                            <u><strong>Charge</strong></u><br/><br/>
                            Base Rent: <br/><br/>
                            <template if:true={hasPetFees}>Monthly Pet Rent: <br/><br/></template>
                            <template if:true={hasParkingFees}>Monthly Parking Fees: <br/><br/></template>
                            <template if:true={hasAdditionalFees}>Additional Fees: <br/><br/></template>
                            Total:
                            </font>
                        </div>
                        <template if:true={isEnabled}>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                                <font size="2">
                                <u><strong>Amount</strong></u><br/><br/>
                                ${rent.Monthly_Rent__c}<br/><br/>
                                <template if:true={hasPetFees}>${rent.Pet_Fees__c} <br/><br/></template>
                                <template if:true={hasParkingFees}>${rent.Parking_Fees__c} <br/><br/></template>
                                <template if:true={hasAdditionalFees}>${rent.Additional_Fees__c} <br/><br/></template>
                                ${rent.Total__c}
                            </font>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
         
                <iframe height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://smoothstack35-dev-ed--c.develop.vf.force.com/apex/paypal"></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
    </lightning-card>

</template>
```

Comment: Lightning message service...?

Comment: I don't think the lightning message service works when the VF page is in an iframe

Comment: How else can a VF page be in the same page as an LWC?